# SQLAlchemy session somehow implicitly creates entry when instantiating pure python model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-many

I see some behaviour with `SQLAlchemy` that is unexpected to me. In a specific scenario of a `many-to-many` relationship an entry is added to the `session` object even though the `add()` method is never called.

Code:

```
# orm.py
metadata = MetaData()


class Student:
    id: int
    classes: list

    def __init__(self, classes: list, id: int = None):
        self.id = id
        self.classes = classes


class Class:
    id: int
    students: list

    def __init__(self, students: list, id: int = None):
        self.id = id
        self.students = students


students = Table(
    'students',
    metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
)

classes = Table(
    'classes',
    metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
)

student_classes = Table(
    'student_classes',
    metadata,
    Column('student_id', Integer, ForeignKey('students.id')),
    Column('class_id', Integer, ForeignKey('classes.id')),
    UniqueConstraint('student_id', 'class_id'),
)


def start_mappers():
    mapper(Student, students, properties={
        'classes': relationship(Class, secondary=student_classes, back_populates='students')
    })
    mapper(Class, classes, properties={
        'students': relationship(Student, secondary=student_classes, back_populates='classes')
    })
```

```
# test.py

class Test(unittest.TestCase):


    def test_adding_students_and_classes(self):
        engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
        metadata.create_all(engine)
        session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
        start_mappers()
        session = session_factory()
        student = Student(classes=[])
        session.add(student)

        a_class = Class(students=[student])
        self.assertEqual(session.query(Class).count(), 0) # fails because count() = 1
```

The test above fails because creating an instance of `Class` which is a pure python model somehow implicitly triggers an entry to be added to the session.

I am confused because I would expect that the session only gets mutated when explicitly calling one of the methods specific in the docs such as `add()` or `delete()`.

Additionally I am confused about how `SQLAlchemy` is even aware that I am creating an instance of `Class`. Is there some sort of listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `mapper(Class, ...)` instruments `Class`, so it is not "pure" anymore. The relationships defined seem to be using default [cascade](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/cascades.html) configuration, which includes [save-update](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/cascades.html#save-update). In this case because the `Student` instance has been added to the session, it pulls the `Class` instance in the session as well, through its `students` relationship. By default autoflush kicks in before each query, and since the `Class` is pending, it is persisted before

```
session.query(Class).count()
```

is run.

Comment: > "Calling mapper(Class, ...) instruments Class" Can I assume that turning off autoflush will prevent this implicit behaviour?

Comment: It will prevent sending the pending insert in this case, but in general it does not affect the `relationship` cascade. The new entity is still added to the session, and will be flushed at least on commit.

If you're wondering, those cascades are there to allow forming more or less complex object graphs, adding just the "root" (or any part, really) to the session, but having it all sort itself out for you.

Comment: What I am looking for is a way to disable this implicit session behavior. Basically I want the session only to change when I explicitly call one of the mutation methods. With the framework under the hood listening to me creating domain models and causing some side effects I‘m having a hard time understanding what‘s going on.

Comment: I think one way to achieve that could be to explicitly configure the `relationship` attributes to not cascade. Pass `cascade=""` to the relationships, but I am unfortunately not sure if that will also disable some other useful behaviour that depends on it. Probably not, but do test.

Comment: This would however also disable any database cascading behaviour such as deletion right? What I'm interested in is remove any listeners on the domain model and instead limit any session mutations to explicit calls to the session. I.e. `model = MyModel(...)` should not have any side effects.

Comment: It does not disable DB cascades, those are configured in the foreign key constraints. The relationship cascades take place on the ORM side of things.